# How do I increase the overall font size in GnuCash on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, fonts

Apparently GnuCash has no built-in way of increasing font size (I have absolutely no idea why).  Googling suggests I should be able to increase system-wide gtk app font size with gnome-control-center, but on Linux Mint, there is no "appearance" or font size section to g-c-c.  I tried fiddling with Menu->Applications->Preference->Appearance->Fonts but that did not change GnuCash's font size.  I'm on Mint 13 with gnucash 2.4.10.

Comment: This worked for me: https://superuser.com/questions/332716/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-in-gnucash-on-os-x using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method #1

Per the official [GNUCash FAQ](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q:_How_get_I_rid_of_strange_unreadable_characters_or_adjust_the_font_size), edit the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0.gnucash`

```
style "font"
{
  font_name = "Arial Narrow 12"
}
widget_class "*" style "font"
gtk-font-name = "Arial Narrow 12”
```

#### Method #2

Take a look at this tutorial titled: [Customizing GTK Apps](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Customizing_GTK_Apps). You should be able to add the following to your .gtkrc-mine file:

```
style "schrift"
{
font_name = "DejaVu Sans 10"
}
widget_class "*" style "schrift"
gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 10"
```

See the tutorial for all the steps.

Comment: @OleTange - it probably didn't work for you b/c you don't have DejaVu Sans 10 font locally. In any case I've updated this answer to include the example that's now in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Running GnuCash 3.1 I had to modify my `$HOME/.config/gnucash/gtk-3.0.css` to have

```
* {
 font: 18px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I figured this out by following the instructions at 
https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/GTK3#Font_Size_in_Documents and the less-clear information at https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ#Q:_Where_can_I_find_the_gtk_resource_file.3F